Issues with Conversion of keypointrcnn_resnet50_fpn Torchvision Model from ONNX to TensorRT Engine
I am having a lot of difficulties converting a keypointrcnn_resnet50_fpn model from ONNX to TensorRT. I have done an extensive search on how to do so, and couldn't find anything that enables me to generate the engine.
Here's how I exported the ONNX model.
torch.onnx.export(model.cpu(),
                    input_tensor.cpu(),
                    onnx_file_path,
                    export_params = True,
                    do_constant_folding = False,
                    input_names = ['input'],
                    output_names = ['boxes', 'labels', 'scores', 'keypoints', 'keypoints_scores'],
                    dynamic_axes = {'input': {2 : 'height', 3 : 'width'}},
                    opset_version = 19
                    )

Here's how I prepared the ONNX model before conversion, and here's how I tried to convert.
    # load the ONNX model
    onnx_model = onnx.load(onnx_file_path)
    # simplify the model
    model_simp, check = simplify(onnx_model)
    # export the simplified model
    if check == True:
        onnx.save(model_simp, f"_simplified{onnx_file_name}")
    else:
        print("ERROR: Failed to simplify and save model")

    # re-export model suitable for TensorRT conversion
    cmd = f"python3 -m onnxruntime.transformers.optimizer \
            --input=_simplified{onnx_file_name} \
            --output=_optimized{onnx_file_name} \
            "
    subprocess.run(cmd, shell = True)
    cmd = f"python3 -m onnxruntime.quantization.preprocess \
            --input=_optimized{onnx_file_name} \
            --output=_q_preprocessed{onnx_file_name} \
            "
    subprocess.run(cmd, shell = True)

    # re-export model with inferred shape
    reloaded_model = onnx.load('_q_preprocessed_keypointrcnn_resnet50_fpn_o19.onnx')
    onnx.checker.check_model(reloaded_model)
    inferred_model = onnx.shape_inference.infer_shapes(reloaded_model, check_type = True, strict_mode = True, data_prop = True)
    onnx.save(inferred_model, f"_shape_inferred{onnx_file_name}")

    # ====

    # check validity of model prior to conversion
    cmd = f"polygraphy run _shape_inferred{onnx_file_name} --onnxrt"
    subprocess.run(cmd, shell = True)

    # ====

    # generate TensorRT engine
    cmd = f"~/.../TensorRT-10.0.0.6/bin/trtexec \
            --onnx=_shape_inferred{onnx_file_name} \
            --minShapes=input:1x3x512x512 \
            --optShapes=input:2x3x512x512 \
            --maxShapes=input:5x3x512x512 \
            --saveEngine=_final_keypointrcnn_resnet50_fpn.trt \
            --useCudaGraph \
            "
    subprocess.run(cmd, shell = True)

At the last step of conversion to TensorRT engine, I get the following error.
[E] Error[4]: [shapeContext.cpp::operator()::3946] Error Code 4: Shape Error (reshape wildcard -1 has infinite number of solutions or no solution. Reshaping [0,8] to [0,-1,4].)
[E] [TRT] ModelImporter.cpp:826: While parsing node number 447 [Reshape -> "/roi_heads/Reshape_1_output_0"]:
[E] [TRT] ModelImporter.cpp:829: --- Begin node ---
    input: "/roi_heads/Flatten_output_0"
    input: "/roi_heads/Concat_2_output_0"
    output: "/roi_heads/Reshape_1_output_0"
    name: "/roi_heads/Reshape_1"
    op_type: "Reshape"
    attribute {
      name: "allowzero"
      i: 0
      type: INT
    }

Does anyone have suggestions on how to get past this problem? I used netron to look into the architecture, and see that the problem is in this region. I appreciate any suggestion in this topic. Thanks.


torchvision detection models aren't really suitable for the onnx to tensorrt conversion pipeline, as their logic and handling of dynamic shapes often relies on python types. It can be done, but unfortunately you would have to rewrite practically the entire forward pass of KeypointRCNN using either constant shapes, or Tensor attributes for branches and padding.

@simeonovich Thanks for the response. Can you provide some clues as to how to achieve this? How do I ensure that constant shapes are used? Are there examples I can follow?

Sorry, can't really think of any templates for this. The basic idea is to go through each function in forward and replace python lists and integers with tensors, applying padding wherever the torchvision code uses dynamic shapes. This is quite a lot of work, so I would try to look for a KeypointRCNN implementation which can be compiled to an .engine as-is and retrain your model using that.
